# TestNg evluation procedure

Tags: java, testng

Consider two below codes I tried in testng , outuput is different iam not getting why it is executing certain tc first and then other , how testng deciding which tc to run first

**Code 1 :**

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class day1 {
    @Test
    public void a()
    {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    @Test
    public void c()
    {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    @Test
    public void b()
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "c" })
    public void d()
    {
        System.out.println("4");
    }

    @Test
    public void k()
    {
        System.out.println("k");
    }

    @Test
    public void e()
    {
        System.out.println("e");
    }
}
```

**output:**

> 3 e k 1 2 4

**Code 2:**

```
package test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class day1 {
    @Test
    public void b()
    {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    @Test
    public void f()
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    @Test
    public void c()
    {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    @Test
    public void d()
    {
        System.out.println("4");
    }

    @Test
    public void e()
    {
        System.out.println("5");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "e" })
    public void a()
    {
        System.out.println("6");
    }

    @Test
    public void g()
    {
        System.out.println("g");
    }
}
```

**output :**

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 2
>
> g
>
> 6
>
> e

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify `priority` in testNG, it decides the priority by it's internal logic which is based on alphabetical order of their method names irrespective of their place of implementation in the code.
Also, if a Test Method(1) is dependent on other Test Method(2) then Test Method(2) will be executed only when Test Method(1) is passed.

Ideally you should use priority with each Test Method to ensure sequential execution.